# Concatenate only upper case letters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel (2021), I have a cell which contains words:

```
all Upper case LeTters supposed to be In result
```

And I need the result:

```
ULTI
```

How can I do that without VBA (i.e. pure excel functions)?

I searched, but "Upper case" and "concatenate" functions all lead to concatenate AND make upper case, and not the other way around: concatenate IF uppercase.

Although I found one but it looks rather ugly and I think (hope) there is better solution:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE
(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(txt,"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),
"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),
"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t",""),"u",""),"v",""),"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),
"z","")," ","")
```

Comment: Check this video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpjYHMdtBgY)

Comment: Copy it to Google Sheets and use =regexreplace(A1,"[^A-Z]","")

Answer (score 10):

In ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`<sup>‡</sup>:

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A1,TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),,1)))
```

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>If not a single character other than uppercase alpha is present, this would throw and error. In such case, simply add a trailing character other than uppercase alpha to the inner `TEXTSPLIT()`, e.g: `=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A1,TEXTSPLIT(A1&"a",CHAR(ROW(65:90)),,1)))`</sub>

---

For Excel 2021:

```
=LET(x,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),CONCAT(IF((CODE(x)>64)*(CODE(x)<91),x,"")))
```

Comment: I was thinking to split by the opposite, it saves one `TEXTSPLIT` function call, but you need to include the entire exclusion list. For this example, we have only letters and space: `=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A1, VSTACK(" ",CHAR(ROW(97:122))),1))`, but in a more general case you need to add numbers, punctuation signs, etc..then it results in a larger formula, for example: `=LET(seq, SEQUENCE(224,,32), idx, FILTER(seq, (seq<65) + (seq > 90)), CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A1, CHAR(idx),,1)))`

Comment: @DavidLeal, Appreciate it but tbh I'm going to stick to my guns here, I do not see a benefit in creating a variable 1st, then use a `FILTER()` etc.

Comment: yes, it is better your approach @JvdV at the end, I was sharing my thoughts on this, and I asked myself why you delimited first by upper case, so I was trying to do the other way around, but at the end, it is better the way you did at least shorter. Great solution!

Comment: @DavidLeal, yeah no worries. Thanks! Btw, small nitpick, using `FILTER()` has the added deficit that in case of no uppercase alphabet chars, your suggestion would return an error whereas a nested `TEXTSPLIT()` would return empty string values resulting in a final empty string after `CONCAT()`. Just a small added benefit there. One the other hand, mine would throw an error in case of *only* uppercase chars. To be safe `=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A1,TEXTSPLIT(A1&"a",CHAR(ROW(65:90)),,1)))` might be wiser.

Comment: Revolutionary! Sets a precedent for string-parsing in Excel without the need to parse each element within the string.

Answer (score 1):

Another one for MS365;

```
=LET(
Input,A1,
LetterArray,MID(Input,SEQUENCE(LEN(Input)),1),
Filtered, FILTER(LetterArray, EXACT(LetterArray, UPPER(LetterArray))*(LetterArray<>" ")*(ISERR(NUMBERVALUE(LetterArray))), "No Uppercase letters found"),
TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, Filtered)
)
```

where `A1` contains the text input.

Comment: W@T©H out for any non-alphabetic chars too!....Sorry for nitpicking as these chars are not necessarily in the input as per OP's sample data =)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said Excel 2021 but I managed to cobble together something that >almost< works in Excel 2010.

There unfortunately doesn't appear to be any way to concatenate arrays in this version so I had to make a UDF for that part but I believe the "CONCAT" function in newer versions might actually work instead of the UDF I had to make. If someone could test that for me, that would be great x)

LET would make this a lot shorter as well... Also this is an array formula, so entered with ctrl+shift+enter

```
=SUBSTITUTE(myConcat(IF(EXACT(MID(O1;ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(O1)));1);UPPER(MID(O1;ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(O1)));1)));UPPER(MID(O1;ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(O1)));1));""));" ";"")
```

the "cheat" part is myConcat, everything else is built in formulas.

```
Function myConcat(ByVal arr As Variant) As String
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            myConcat = myConcat & arr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

*numbers and special characters will throw this off unfortunately. I could probably figure out the numbers, not sure about the special characters.