# How to get rid of unwanted characters from emojis in cells on Excel?

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I am working on cleaning a dataset on Excel about Social Media Influencers on Instagram in September 2022, and within the name column, names have weird characters that comes from emojis. I have taken this dataset from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ramjasmaurya/top-1000-social-media-channels?select=social+media+influencers+-+instagram+sep-2022.csv.

Can you please help me with a tip on how to get rid of those characters and therefore clean my dataset on Excel?

Example on cell C3 in this image:

[image]

I tried the Find/ Replace option on Excel but it takes so much time to do so.

Comment: You can use the idea provided by @JvdV on his answer to the following question: [Concatenate only upper case letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460384/concatenate-only-upper-case-letters), but using `UNICHAR` function instead. The problem of your data set is to identify all possible alphabet letters in all languages of the world, plus punctuation symbols to be included. I don't know if there is a specific range for the emojis, so you can exclude them (see my comment to his answer). UNICODE character set is huge.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do not answer questions which do not show any efforts but I was curious as to what kind of data were you talking about.

I inspected your data and found characters which cannot be cleaned with just find and replace. You not only had non printable characters but also non english characters. I could identify 3 languages besides English. *Urdu*, *Punjabi* and *Chinese*.

Try this code for me. What it does is, it checks the Asc character and checks if it is between 0 and 127 (including them).

I tried this code and it cleaned your entire data in about 2 seconds.

**CAUTION**: I have not completely tested this code. Make a backup of your data before you test this code. Lets me know if you see any issues?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim Outliers As String
    Dim AscValue As Long
    Dim CellAddress As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet3
    
    '~~> Start Time (OPTIONAL)
    Debug.Print Now
    
    For Each aCell In ws.UsedRange
        CellValue = aCell.Value
        CellAddress = ""
        
        For i = Len(CellValue) To 1 Step -1
            If Len(Trim(Mid(CellValue, i, 1))) <> 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                AscValue = AscW(Mid(CellValue, i, 1))
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    '~~> Address of the cell which has error (if any)
                    CellAddress = aCell.Address
                    Err.Clear
                Else
                    If AscW(Mid(CellValue, i, 1)) < 0 Or AscW(Mid(CellValue, i, 1)) > 127 Then
                        CellValue = Replace(CellValue, Mid(CellValue, i, 1), "")
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next i
        
        If CellAddress <> "" Then
            If Outliers = "" Then
                Outliers = CellAddress
            Else
                Outliers = Outliers & ", " & CellAddress
            End If
        End If
                
        aCell.Value = CellValue
    Next aCell
    
    If Outliers <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Unable to remove characters from cells " & vbNewLine & Outliers
    End If
    
    '~~> End Time (OPTIONAL)
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to Excel, do I need to run the code in VBA?

Comment: Yes. You need to paste the code in a module and then run it. If you are not sure where and how to do it, then you can see that in [Visual Basic Editor - An Introduction](https://youtu.be/lftEbmYwh-U). Or if you want to learn VBA from scratch then you may want to see [Learn VBA from scratch and for free](https://www.youtube.com/c/SiddharthRout). Disclaimer: This is my YT channel.