# extract alphanumeric or numeric substring from a string in excel

Tags: excel

I am new to excel, and this logic seems very tough for me,

I have a text in a cell for ex - 'this is a test string and code: 6676RtA01' and I need to extract this - 6676RtA01

Logic - I need to extract the alphaneumeric or numeric code which appears imeediate after the word code/codes ignoring any special character, spaces or underscores, brackets etc

the word code/codes should be case insensitive, and if it found multiple code then it should seperate it with ';'
here are few ex -

- 'test string', output - blank
- 'another test string CODE' 6657Yuyt9 and codes: 9989', output - 6657Yuyt9;9989
- 'with code bracket the (Code A011261)', output - A011261

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @Rory, Version 2208

Comment: So the desired extraction(s) always contains at least one numeric? Otherwise, I'm not sure how we would discount 'bracket' as a potential output from your third example.

Comment: @JosWoolley, yes, the desired output will always has at least one numeric in it for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fully rigorous, I think you need to discount all non-alphanumeric characters which could occur in the string and also retain the case of the desired extractions:

```
    =LET(
    ζ,A1,
    ξ,LAMBDA(α,β,CHAR(SEQUENCE(α,,β))),
    γ,VSTACK(ξ(10,48),ξ(26,65),ξ(26,97)),
    δ,TEXTSPLIT(ζ,γ,,1),
    ε,TEXTSPLIT(ζ,δ),
    κ,DROP(ε,,1),
    λ,SEQUENCE(10),
    TEXTJOIN(";",,
        FILTER(κ,
            (1-ISNA(XMATCH(DROP(ε,,-1),"code"&{"","s"})))
            *MMULT(TOROW(λ),1-ISERR(FIND(λ-1,κ))),
        "")
    )
)
```

*Corrected thanks to DavidLeal*.

Comment: @JosWolley, If I am not mistaken, using your formula you get a false positive for this case: `this is codet A01 and this is the code A02`. It returns: `A01;A02` instead of `A02`. Since `codet` is not a valid code prefix. This is because how `SEARCH` works.

Comment: @DavidLeal Good spot, thanks. Will amend so that only "code" and "codes" are considered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. It considers the additional rule indicated in the comments: *The code has at least one number*. This approach prevents any false positives, which would produce using `SEARCH/FIND` as part of the solution. For example, for the following string: `codeine A10 is not a code A20` would return `A20` only.

```
=LET(A, A1, set, CHAR(VSTACK(ROW($48:$57),ROW($65:$90), ROW($97:$122))),
 stxt, TEXTSPLIT(A, TEXTSPLIT(A,set,,1)), xm, XMATCH(stxt, {"code","codes"}), 
 idx, FILTER(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(xm))+1,1-ISNA(xm)), codes, INDEX(stxt,idx), 
 isCode, BYCOL(1-ISERR(FIND(SEQUENCE(10),codes)), LAMBDA(x, MAX(x))),
 TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(codes, isCode,"")))
```

The idea of using `TEXTSPLIT(A, TEXTSPLIT(set,,1)` to split and remove unwanted characters I took the idea from the answer provided by @jvdV to the following question: [Concatenate only upper case letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460384/concatenate-only-upper-case-letters). Once we have the information split (`stxt`) you can use `XMACHT` to find the column index of `code` or `codes`.

Once we have the token positions (`xm`). The code candidates are in the following column. The name `idx` finds the corresponding columns. Having the columns, we can find the candidate code  (`codes`) from `stxt` via `INDEX`.

Now we need to check if the `codes` are valid ones (`isCode`), i.e. at least one number. We use `BYCOL` and search for digits (`SEQUENCE(10)`). The input of `BYCOL` is an array of `10xm`, where `m` is the number of candidate `codes`. If a number was found return `1` at a given row position, otherwise `0`. Using `MAX` by column will produce the boolean array we need to filter via `FILTER`. Finally, we put the result delimited by a comma via `TEXTJOIN`.

The previous logic can be wrapped in a user `LAMBDA` function `GET_CODES`, so we can generate an array version as follows:

```
=LET(A,A1:A6,GET_CODES,LAMBDA(x,LET(set,CHAR(VSTACK(ROW(48:57),ROW(65:90),
 ROW(97:122))), stxt,TEXTSPLIT(x,TEXTSPLIT(x,set,,1)),
 xm,XMATCH(stxt,{"code","codes"}),
 idx,FILTER(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(xm))+1,1-ISNA(xm)), codes, INDEX(stxt,idx),
 isCode, BYCOL(1-ISERR(FIND(SEQUENCE(10),codes)),LAMBDA(x, MAX(x))),
 TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(codes, isCode,"")))), BYROW(A, LAMBDA(x, GET_CODES(x))))
```

Here is the output using `GET_CODES`:
[image: excel output]
As you can see:

- Row `3` identifies correctly that `bracket` is not a valid code
- Row `4` identifies correctly only `A02` because for `A01` the token is not `code`/`codes`. Testing it doesn't generate a false positive.
- Rows `5` and `6` return empty because there is no valid code in the string

Comment: I think we're basically using the same approach!

Comment: The only significant difference is that I use `XMATCH` but now with your update, it is very similar. I found a way to identify valid codes using `BYROW` and `MAX` and you took the approach of using `MMULT` and playing with DROP. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, you could use something like:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),")"," "),")"," "))," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[contains(preceding::*[1],'code') and translate(.,'1234567890','')!=.]")),"")
```

I'd imagine there are simpler ways... :)

Comment: What about other punctuation that may be present? For example, "Code A1, code A2 and code A3" would return 'a1,;a2;a3'

Answer (score 0):

My effort would be:

```
=LET(
CharList, MID(C2,SEQUENCE(LEN(C2)),1),
TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,DROP(CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(FILTER(CharList, ISNUMBER(FIND(UPPER(CharList),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "))))," ", "code",,1),2),1))
)
```

I don't know if that's simpler than @Rory's answer (which I don't understand due to not knowing XML filtering), it's only 10 characters shorter.

Comment: Just realised a bug; making the TEXTPLIT Case insensitive has converted all outputs to lowercase. Not as good a solution after all, sorry

Comment: Also, what about the condition that the extractions should contain at least one numeric? And words containing the letters 'code' will return false positives. Your set-up will return "and;a1" for an example such as 'UK postcodes and code A1'.