# Excel: Extract a sequence of n numbers from a string with a formula

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, extract, sequence

I have a cell in excel which holds a 6 digit number which I need to extract. That cell may contain stings or other numbers but fortunately no other number of 6 digits. (spacing, number of words, location number may vary)
Is there a way to extract that 6 digit number only?

I cannot use VBA for this, if must be a formula

| Cell A1 | Cell B1 |
| --- | --- |
| ab 12 abcd 1234 abcdef 123456 abcdefgh 12345678 | 123456 |

Comment: Will the desired extraction always have a space immediately before and immediately after it?

Comment: It always will, thanks again for your excellent solution @JosWoolley!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safer to test each individual character within the parsed substrings for numericalness. Otherwise, substrings such as *2-june* or *1.2E04* can be returned undesirably.

```
=LET(
    ζ,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),
    FILTER(ζ,(LEN(ζ)=6)*MMULT(SEQUENCE(,6,,0),1-ISERR(0+MID(ζ,SEQUENCE(6),1)))=6)
)
```

That said, the following should also be sufficiently rigorous:

```
=LET(ζ,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),FILTER(ζ,(LEN(ζ)=6)*(1-ISERR(0+(ζ&"**0")))))
```

though the latter will return decimals such as `1.2345` whereas the former won't.

Comment: Wow @Jos you were quick with that! Your first option is brilliant. The textsplit col_delimiter up top needs to be set to a space, this works as the number is always led and followed by one. Thank you!

Comment: @JosWoolley, I think `TEXTSPLIT` doesn't work with an empty string as a delimiter, maybe you mean `" "`

Comment: Ooops. Thanks both - typoed `""` instead of `" "`. Will amend.

Comment: @JosWoolley is there any scenario I am missing with this approach: `=LET(ζ,TEXTSPLIT(A1," ",,1), FILTER(ζ,(LEN(ζ)=6)*(1-ISERR(1*ζ))))` compared to your second formula? Just trying to understand why you append: `**0` maybe to eliminate some cases, but I am not able to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal See the first sentence in my post. Without concatenating `"**0"` to each substring, you could potentially get false positives, for example if `A1` contained '*abc 2-june*' (for English-language versions), or '*abc 1.2E04*'.

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley. It looks like that the `**0` expression is interpreted by Excel as `10^0`. When the prefix is a number, so: `=0 + "12**0"`returns `12` and, `=0 + "12**-1"` returns `1.2` and so on. For: `0 + "2-june**0"` returns `#VALUE!` so for this case it cannot be interpreted like that. **Do you know if this behavior is documented somewhere?** Thanks!

Comment: @DavidLeal `"**0"` is equivalent to `"E0"`, i.e. represents scientific notation with an index of 0. Not sure if the `"E"` in `"E0"` is locale-dependent, so `"**0"` seems a safer choice. Catenation of `"**0"` ensures that strings such as `"12-june"` become `"12-june**0"` and so can no longer be interpreted as numerics. The same also applies to strings which happen to bear a resemblance to numerics formatted as scientific notation, e.g. `"1.2E04"`. Not sure if it's documented anywhere - I learnt it from someone else.

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley! I suspected something like that, another Excel hidden feature.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to use `FILTERXML()`. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()=6][number()=.]")
```

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` will construct a valid XML string to process by FILTERXML() formula.
- XPath parameter //s will return all nodes where `[string-length()=6]` will filter only 6 digit nodes and `[number()=.]` will return number values only..

[image]

Comment: Depends if the OP would want to extract decimals as well, for example for 'abc 1.2345 def' your formula would return '1.2345'.

Comment: @JosWoolley If OP doesn't want then have to adjust the formula.

Comment: @Harun, I didn't want decimals but normally my data shouldn't contain any. Also you have the added advantage that your solutions presents directly as a number. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
=LET(A,A2, s,6, n,TEXTSPLIT(A,TEXTSPLIT(A,CHAR(ROW(48:57)),,1)), 
 FILTER(n, LEN(n)=s))
```

The idea was taken from the answer provided by @JvdV to this question: [Concatenate only upper case letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460384/concatenate-only-upper-case-letters). If you want to cast the result as a number multiply the `FILTER` result by `1`. I am assuming you are looking for **natural numbers**, for any other kind of numbers the formula needs to be adjusted or take a different approach.

[image: output]

A shorter formula and easier to understand can be achieved using `SEQUENCE` instead of `CHAR` and `ROW`, thanks to @VBasic2008:

```
=LET(A,A2, s,6, n,TEXTSPLIT(A,TEXTSPLIT(A,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,1)),
 FILTER(n, LEN(n)=s))
```

If there is more than one number that satisfies the condition, it will return more than one row. You can combine them together in a single row, wrapping the output of `FILTER` (`f`) with `TEXTJOIN(",",,f)`.

Comment: your assumption is absolutely correct, natural numbers only. This works beautifully too. Thank you

Comment: Just the way I like it! A tiny remark though: with the appearance of the `SEQUENCE` function, many 'exotic combos' have become extinct i.e. instead of `CHAR(ROW(48:57))` you can simply use `SEQUENCE(10,,0)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks, I added your suggestion and credit to you. In this case, it is easier to understand using just `SEQUENCE`, shorter but just by one character, but more importantly, it is more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If `LET` function is available then following can be tested. It is bit long-winded. In the latest versions of Excel, `TEXTSPLIT` is also available which can reduce it further.

`=LOOKUP(10^6,LET(x,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99*SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))+1),99)),IF(LEN(x)=6,IF(ISNUMBER(x+0),x+0,"a"),"a")))`

Comment: What if the the desired extraction is at the end of the string, e.g. 'abc 123456'?

Comment: @JosWoolley: tested with a string like `ab 12 abcd 1234 abcdef 1234567 abcdefgh 123456` which returns correctly `123456`. The reason for adding space before was to simplify the sequence portion of the formula, post padding is not needed. I have not given thought to the part where OP my have something like `OP123456 6859` and still considers `123456` should be the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a space before and after the sequence:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" , ",TRUE,IF(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "))=6*ISNUMBER(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "))),TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Will give false positives for examples such as 'abc 2-june' (at least for English language versions of Excel).

Comment: Absolutely right

Comment: @user11222393, I love this as it is easier for the layman like me to understand. I didn't get any false positives yet but will keep testing to see if I can f*** it up hahaha. Thank you